# How to convert lerp to cubic easing in?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, easing, lerp

I need to convert the following code from using lerp to using cubic easing in, but I don't know what to do with the returned float value from the cubic easing in function, because I'm using Vector3 instead of floats. Can someone please give me a hint?

```
    if (Vector3.Distance(activeTween.Target.position, activeTween.EndPos) > 0.1f)
        {
            float fraction = (Time.time - activeTween.StartTime) / activeTween.Duration;
            activeTween.Target.position = Vector3.Lerp(activeTween.StartPos, activeTween.EndPos, fraction);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cubic function that is 0 at the start and 1 and the end.
I would try something like:

```
public float EaseIn(float t)
{
    return t * t * t;
}

if (Vector3.Distance(activeTween.Target.position, activeTween.EndPos) > 0.1f)
{
    float fraction = (Time.time - activeTween.StartTime) / activeTween.Duration;

    activeTween.Target.position = Vector3.Lerp(activeTween.StartPos, activeTween.EndPos, EaseIn(fraction));
}
```

Assuming that `fraction` was already going from 0 to 1.

Comment: thanks! I thought lerp is totally different from easing, bluh

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just use it in place of your `fraction` in the `Vector3.Lerp`.

Lerp is just the linear interpolation of vectors, i.e. 0.3 means 30% from one and 70% from the other. If we want non linear interpolation we can just apply some arbitrary function to the input value. For example, that 0.3 may be transformed to 0.027, and that can then be used as the input to Lerp to get 2.7% / 97.3% blend instead.

Comment: thanks! I dont know easing is based on lerp...